# Draw a line in footer using mdpf

Tags: mpdf

I am using mdpf. I want to draw a line in my footer. How can I do so? I am using folowing code in footer.

```php
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<div class="pdf_date" style="color:black
text-align:left;" >{DATE j-m-Y}</div>
<div class="pdf_pagination" style="color:black; text-align:right;" >
{PAGENO}
</div>'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add footer for the mPDF in configuration part.follow this path `admin/config/user-interface/mpdf`.

```
<table><tr><td style ="border-bottom:2px solid black; width:100%;"> </td></tr></table>
```